# how to create directive for daterangepicker?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I came across this nice datepicker on this site: http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/. It works fine here : http://plnkr.co/edit/qmj5urjBb4TdtUYCuwap?p=preview

However I would like to make a directive to reuse in my site:

```
app.directive('dateRange', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'picker.html'
    };
});
```

picker.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css"/>
<script src="http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/bower_components/momentjs/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/ng-bs-daterangepicker.js"></script>
<input type="daterange" ng-model="dates4" ranges="ranges">
```

I used my directive in an index.html:

```
  <date-range></date-range>
```

Even though it works in the 1st plunkr I cant get it too work as a directive. Why am I getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=filtersampl….com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-beta.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A139)
```

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/nr8iOIpIDSf26DxiWEJF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I have another code for datepicker try this if you found helpful,

```
datepicker.directive('datepicker', function($compile,$modal) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {

                element.addClass("datepicker-input");

                element.after("<span class='datepicker-icon'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></span>");

                if (attr.withmore) {
                    element.addClass("withMore");
                    element.next(".datepicker-icon").after('<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="selectdaterange()" class="more-datepicker-icon" tooltip title="Advanced Date Search"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>');
                    $compile(element.next(".datepicker-icon").next('.more-datepicker-icon'))(scope);
                }

                element.datepicker({
                    format: attr.format ? attr.format : 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                    autoclose: true,
                    todayHighlight: true
                });

                scope.selectdaterange = function(){
                    scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        template  : '<div class="modal-header">'+
                                        '<h3 class="modal-title">Select Daterange</h3>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="modal-body">'+
                                        'You have not selected any News to delete. Please select at least one News to delete.'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                                        '<button class="btn btn-important" ng-click="deleteCancel()">OK</button>'+
                                    '</div>',
                        scope : scope
                    });
                }

            }
        };
    });
```